# Renaming Column names and creating new column names using apache beam

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a CSV file which has 2 columns named **first_name** and **last_name**.

I am using dataflow with direct_runner.

My use case to first change the column names to **name** and **surname** and then use PTransform to concat name and surname and generate a new column as **employee_name**

code :

```
import apache_beam as beam

p2= beam.Pipeline()

def splitrow(element):
  return element.split(',')

demodata0=(
    
    p2
      |beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://demo/MOCK_DATA.csv')
      |beam.Map(splitrow)
      |beam.Map(lambda element : ( element[0]+" "+element[1]))
      |beam.io.WriteToText('gs://demo/temp/output2')

)

p2.run()
```

input table :

```
first_name      last_name
John             Miller
Smith            scott
```

output table :

```
name   surname   employee_name
john    Miller    John Miller
Smith   Scott     smith Scott
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: hey @dnnshssm My question is how can I create a new column and also even change column names in apache beam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked with CSV files in beam before, but I would suggest using a custom DoFn (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo)). It would look something like this:

```
class EnrichCsvData(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    output_pcoll = {}
    # i don't know if the inputs are strings, you might need to adjust the code if not
    output_pcoll["name"] = element[0]
    output_pcoll["surname"] = element[1]
    output_pcoll["employee_name"] = element[0] + element[1]
    
    return output_pcoll
```

and then call it in your pipeline:

```
p2
  |beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://demo/MOCK_DATA.csv')
  |beam.Map(splitrow)
  |beam.ParDo(EnrichCsvData())
  |...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for help. I landed up in getting the desired output using custom DoFn as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own DoFn is great when you have complex logic and need to do some heavy lifting. If you just need to select some columns names and have relatively simple definitions as is the case here, you can use beam.Select() for creating [schemas](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-schemas).

```
# Copyright 2022 Google LLC. 
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

import apache_beam as beam

p2= beam.Pipeline()

def splitrow(element):
  return element.split(',')

demodata0=(
    
    p2
      |beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://demo/MOCK_DATA.csv')
      |beam.Map(splitrow)
      |beam.Select(name=lambda element: element[0],
                   surname=lambda element: element[1],
                   full_name=lambda element: element[0]+" "+element[1])
      |beam.io.WriteToText('gs://demo/temp/output2')

)

p2.run()
```